# c++ What happens when alias to unique_ptr goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

If I have a unique pointer and I create an alias for it in a function, and that alias goes out of scope, why doesn't the original unique_ptr also get destroyed? After all, 'b' as defined in the function below is basically the same object in memory as 'x'. What is going on behind the scenes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void testfunc(std::unique_ptr<int>& x) {
  std::unique_ptr<int>& b = x;
}
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int(5));
  std::cout << *a << std::endl; // 5
  testfunc(a);
  std::cout << *a << std::endl; // 5
}
```

Comment: What you have are *references* (not aliases) and they only reference an actual variable, whose life-time doesn't end. Look at them as a kind of (non-smart) pointer. when the life-time of a pointer ends, it doesn't mean what they are pointing to will end.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "*What you have are references (not aliases)*" - technically, by **definition**, a reference **IS** an alias. How the compiler implements the alias is up to the compiler vendor to decide (most use a pointer).

Comment: It would not be much fun if every time you passed a variable to a function by reference it got destroyed. So called "out parameters" would be a thing of the pase....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/reference) is can be considered like an alias to an element, hence it *references* another variable by taking up its *value* and working *just like it does*, but it doesn't get destroyed until called by the destructor or forcibly destroyed by the programmer **which will also destroy the variable it references... since a reference *is just an editable alias***... However their lifespan differs since a *non-reference* type can be moved and it becomes *out of scope*...

> "*What is going on behind the scenes?*"

Inside the memory, the reference allows us to *change the value* of an element and if often used *instead of pointers which were a common practice in C*... **But**, its value cannot be **moved** unless passed... A reference's value won't change unless changed using an **assignment operation** *directly* or *indirectly* *i.e,* from the function parameter *`x`* which itself is an *alias*...

Like: `x = std::make_unique<int>(6);` will change the value of `a` to 6 instead... *But what you have done here instead is...*

```
auto& b = x;
```

Nothing actually happens except the value that `x`(*references to `a`*) is referencing to is **copied** and passed to `b` (which just acts like **another alias**)... So it is similar to doing: `auto& b = a;`, but since `a` is outside the scope, it references `a`'s value *indirectly*...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void testfunc(std::unique_ptr<int>& x)
{
    auto& b(x); // 'b' is an alias of 'x' and 'x' is an alias of 'a'
    b = std::make_unique<int>(6); // Setting 'b' to 6 meaning setting 'a' to 6...
    /* Now you can't do 'x = b' since you cannot assign a value to an alias and it is
       like a 'circular assignment operation'...*/
}
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int(5));
    std::cout << *a << std::endl; // 5 : Nothing happens, just initialization...
    testfunc(a);                  // It does not affect the reference...
    std::cout << *a << std::endl; /* 6 : Since reference is an 'alias', you
                                     changed 'a' as well...*/
} // It is freed after use by the destructor...
```

So, a general advice from people would be that you should avoid references if you are unsure of what it does (It can *change* the **real variable** if you are unknown of its consequences)... and take some time to [learn about them](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/)...

If you destroy the **original** however..., all the *references* themselves will become invalidated... In such a case, when trying to access the value of *destroyed* (**nullified**) object is *undefined* causing [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#References)...

Comment: "stores addresses inside it" thats an implementation detail that may or may not be so.

Comment: "and never goes out of scope" references go out of scope like all other variables.

Answer (score 2):

What you're using is a reference, and a reference in C++ is a distinct type from what it is referencing. You can interact with an object through a reference, but the reference itself and the object being referred to have separate lifetimes. When one is destroyed, the other doesn't automatically get destroyed. This means you can pass a reference into a function and then at the end of a function when the reference is destroyed the original object is still valid. This allows passing around large complex objects without needing to copy or even moving them. It's a implementation detail, but it's common for compilers to simply use a pointer "behind the scenes" as references.

As a side note, this aspect of references in C++ leads to the infamous dangling reference issue. If you hold a reference to some object and that object is destroyed the reference you have is now technically invalid, and you'll invoke undefined behavior if you use it. Unfortunately there is nothing built into the language to automatically detect or deal with this situation. You must architect your program to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void testfunc(std::unique_ptr<int>& x) {  // you take a reference to a unique_ptr
  std::unique_ptr<int>& b = x;            // which will do nothing to the lifetime of
}                                         // the unique_ptr you pass to the function,
                                          // then you assign the passed parameter
                                          // to another reference. again, that does
                                          // nothing to the lifetime of the original.
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int(5));
  std::cout << *a << std::endl; // 5
  testfunc(a);
  std::cout << *a << std::endl; // 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> After all, 'b' as defined in the function below is basically the same object in memory as 'x'.

Not at all. `x` is a reference. A reference is not an object, and no constructor or destructor is called for it. There are no "aliases" for variables. There are for types, also known as typedefs.

Consider the same code with pointers instead:

```
void testfunc(std::unique_ptr<int>* x) {
  std::unique_ptr<int>* b = x;
}
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int(5));
  std::cout << *a << std::endl; // 5
  testfunc(&a);
  std::cout << *a << std::endl; // 5
}
```

The only time a reference can affect the lifetime of an object is when a reference binds to a temporary, but even then, it extends the lifetime rather than reducing it:

```
struct A {};

int main() {
    {
        A(); // Constructed and destructed
    }

    {
        A const& a = A(); // Constructed
        // Other instructions
    } // Destructed
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34c76709978d2820)

Comment: A reference can very well be considered an alias.

Comment: @Swordfish Loosely, maybe. But "an alias for X" means "another name for X", not "a reference to X". Which is apparently the whole point of confusion in the question. On the other hand, a type alias is exaclty that: another name for exactly the same thing.

Comment: A reference to `foo x;` is an alias to `x`.